# How to get number of rows for a specific value in a column

Tags: r

I am trying to get the number of rows for a specific column. I have three columns with Name, Age, and major. How can i find out how many BIO majors there are for example from this list.

I have a DF <- (NAME, YEAR, MAJOR, GPA)
I want to have a function so I can eliminate any major with less than 20 people.

so I want something like this, but in actual r code.

```
DF <- function(x){
##  Y <- get number of people for each major
##  GPA [DF$Y < 20] <- NA
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the two methods offered so far are overly complex. Try either of these, the second of which is obviously the "Right way". :-)  (Borrowing @gung's example.)

```
#  1
> tapply( DF$MAJOR, DF$MAJOR, length)
 BIO ECON HIST  LIT MATH 
 181  155  297  303   64 

#  2
> table(DF$MAJOR)

 BIO ECON HIST  LIT

 MATH 
     181  155  297  303   64 

And as far as efficiency?

> system.time( {dt = data.table(DF)
+  foo <- dt[,.N,by=MAJOR] })
   user  system elapsed 
  1.384   0.027   1.417 
> system.time(foo<- table(DF$MAJOR) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.110   0.025   0.134 
#edit:
> system.time( {dt = as.data.table(DF)
+  foo <- dt[,.N,by=MAJOR] })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.064   0.022   0.086
```

The answer the appended question in the comments of how to associate a tabular result with each student record, look at the `ave` function and use the first method with either "["-extraction or with `subset`:

```
 DF$group.size <- ave(DF$MAJOR, DF$MAJOR, length)
 newDF <- DF[ DF$group.size >=20000 , ]
```

Comment: If you use `as.data.table` instead of `data.table` it will be faster.

Comment: It was significantly faster (and added the timing). Faster even than `table()`, but I'm hoping my point comes across that there was an available base-R method that was quite compact, efficient and did not require an additional package.

Comment: I ended up going with something like this, or maybe even exactly this. The other solutions offered were helpful in my thinking about this, but this solution I found was much easier. I needed to have the count in a column in the same data frame so something like this works out well

Answer (score 3):

The basic way to get a count of how many of something you have is to sum up a logical vector where each element of the logical vector is a 1 if the original element is the thing you want to count, or a 0 otherwise.

Lets start with some data:

```
N = 1000
set.seed(2)
DF <- data.frame(NAME=as.character(1:N), 
                 YEAR=sample(c("Freshman","Sophomore","Junior","Senior"),
                             size=N, replace=T), 
                 MAJOR=sample(c("BIO","ECON","HIST","LIT","MATH"),size=N, 
                              replace=T, prob=c(.20, .15, .30, .30, .05)), 
                 GPA=runif(N, min=0, max=4))
```

Thus, we find out how many `BIO` majors you have by:

```
sum(DF$MAJOR=="BIO")
[1] 181
```

If you wanted to know how many you have for every major that exists, you can get a list of the majors with [?unique](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html), and then apply the function above to the list with [?lapply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/lapply.html):

```
lapply(unique(DF$MAJOR), function(x){ sum(DF$MAJOR==x) })
```

Here's a slightly prettier version:

```
cbind(levels(unique(DF$MAJOR)), 
      lapply(unique(DF$MAJOR), function(x){ sum(DF$MAJOR==x) }))
     [,1]   [,2]
[1,] "BIO"  297 
[2,] "ECON" 303 
[3,] "HIST" 181 
[4,] "LIT"  155 
[5,] "MATH" 64
```

You should be able to take it from here.

---

*Update:* @DWin is right, I was making this too complicated.  Since `DF$MAJOR` is a factor, you can simply do:

```
> summary(DF$MAJOR)
 BIO ECON HIST  LIT MATH 
 181  155  297  303   64
```

Comment: Thank You, I tried using table() and merging, and it kept running and would never finish the process, may be because I have over a million observations, but other merges work. I will try your strategy.

Comment: It does not work exactly, the way I want but still a good jump. WOuld you know hot to then merge it into set with all the students. If I were to have a column of number of kids in major in the large data set how would I do this. Basically from there I then want to remove all students from the large dataset for which the number of people in there major is less than 20 thousand. I planned on using the subset() function, but am still new to r and would greatly appreciate the help

Comment: I don't quite follow your comment. Following this operation, you should have a list of counts of majors & be able to tell which majors have fewer students than any given threshold. You can form a new data frame w/o those majors if you want. `toExclude = which(DF$MAJOR%in%c(<list>))`; `DF2 = DF[-toExclude,]`.

Answer (score 3):

Again it's the data.table package grouping functionality to the rescue. There is a '.N' notation that means the number of rows in each group, and it gives you exactly what you need. Borrowing from the previous answer:

```
> N = 1000
> set.seed(2)
> dt <- data.table(NAME=as.character(1:N), 
+                  YEAR=sample(c("Freshman","Sophomore","Junior","Senior"),
+                              size=N, replace=T), 
+                  MAJOR=sample(c("BIO","ECON","HIST","LIT","MATH"),size=N, 
+                               replace=T, prob=c(.20, .15, .30, .30, .05)), 
+                  GPA=runif(N, min=0, max=4))
> dt[,.N,by=MAJOR]
   MAJOR   N
1:  HIST 297
2:   LIT 303
3:   BIO 181
4:  ECON 155
5:  MATH  64
```

So it's now a one-liner. And it's fast too (using N=1000000):

```
> system.time( foo <- cbind(levels(unique(DF$MAJOR)), 
+       lapply(unique(DF$MAJOR), function(x){ sum(DF$MAJOR==x) })) )
     user    system   elapsed 
    0.616     0.050     0.665 
> dt = data.table(DF)
> system.time( foo <- dt[,.N,by=MAJOR] )
     user    system   elapsed 
    0.039     0.002     0.042
```